# Eager Fetch The Model In The Component

Tags: c#, nhibernate

## Base

```
<class name="A" >
<id name="ID" type="AnsiString">
<column name="p_ID_vc" length="50"></column>
<generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
<component name="B">
<many-to-one name="C" lazy="true"/>
</component>
<class/>
```

## Goal

- Fetch C while Get the object A
- Fetch C while Get the List of A

## Problem

I try ↓.but it doesn't work.

```
Query.Fetch(A=>A.B).ThenFetch(B=>B.C).Where(……).
```

## Help

- Anyone knows how to solve it.I need your help.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching over components doesn't work with Linq queries yet. See this issue: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2769

Comment: Thank you. But still sad. I have to make a work around solution.

Comment: should have been a comment instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use HQL to achieve this.. here is how your query should look like:

```
"select a from A a inner join fetch a.B b inner join fetch b.C c where ..."
```

Hope that helps..